# FragmentPagerAdapter: IllegalStateException Can't change container ID of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

First: Sorry for the wall of text/code, but I think most of it is needed to understand the problem.

I am creating an app using `Fragments` in a `ViewPager` and a `TabHost`. The `ViewPager` has a custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` that will feed the various pages in the `ViewPager`. I have ran into a problem where the custom `FragmentPagerAdapter` starts adding the various `Fragments` to the `BackStack`, but it fails at a point where it checks that the container ID (in this case the ID of the `ViewPager`) against the ID of the `Fragments` to add. These are different, thus the program fails. I am fairly new to using `Fragments`, so I am not sure if my code follows best practice. What could be the error in the following?

**The Activity, which inflates the main XML layout.**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private MyViewPager                 mViewPager;
    private FragmentTabHost             mFragmentTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        setupViewPager();
        setupFragmentTabHost();
    }

    private void setupViewPager()
    {
        mViewPager = (MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
    }

    private void setupFragmentTabHost()
    {
        mFragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mFragmentTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mFragmentTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1", null), TabFragment.class, null);
        mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", null), TabFragment.class, null);
        mFragmentTabHost.addTab(mFragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", null), TabFragment.class, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
    }

    public MyViewPager getMyPager()
    {
        return mViewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mFragmentTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        mFragmentTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
}
```

**The main XML file, my_activity.xml, containing the ViewPager, the TabHost and the Fragments for the ViewPager:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <com.mycompany.myapp.gui.mypager.MyViewPager
                android:id="@+id/my_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TabWidget 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.gui.mypager.FilteredRecipesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/filtered_recipes_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.gui.mypager.SelectedRecipesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/selected_recipes_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.gui.mypager.ShoppingListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/shopping_list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that `onCreateView` is called for each custom `Fragment`, they are inflated and the root `View` of each of them are returned. Here is one example, for `FilteredRecipesFragment`. The other custom `Fragments` are similar.

```
public class FilteredRecipesFragment extends Fragment {

    private FilteredRecipesListFragment mFilteredRecipesListFragment;
    private Button showRecipeFilterButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_recipes_fragment, container, false);
        mFilteredRecipesListFragment = (FilteredRecipesListFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filtered_recipes_list_fragment);
        showRecipeFilterButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.show_recipe_filter_dialog_button);
        showRecipeFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new RecipeFilterButtonListener());
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Finally, the custom `ViewPager` and its custom `FragmentPagerAdapter`, where the program fails.

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager{

    private MyActivity mMyActivity;
    private MyPagerAdapter mMyPagerAdapter;

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mMyActivity = (MyActivity) context;
        mMyPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), mMyActivity);
        this.setAdapter(mMyPagerAdapter);
        this.setOnPageChangeListener(mMyActivity);
        this.setCurrentItem(PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST); // Page 0
    }
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private MyActivity mMyActivity;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, MyActivity myActivity)
    {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mMyActivity = myActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position) {
        case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES: // 0
            return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filtered_recipes_fragment);

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES: // 1
            return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.selected_recipes_fragment);

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST: // 2
            return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.shopping_list_fragment);

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return PagerConstants.NUMBER_OF_PAGES; // 3
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return PagerConstants.PAGE_TITLES(position);
    }

}
```

Everything *seems* to be working ok, but after every custom `Fragment` is inflated, the custom `ViewPager` starts to add them too. Here is the stack output from `Eclipse`:

```
06-07 15:37:49.815: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment FilteredRecipesFragment{4605b0e0 #0 id=0x7f09003f android:switcher:2131296318:0}: was 2131296319 now 2131296318
BackStackRecord.doAddOp(int, Fragment, String, int) line: 407   
BackStackRecord.add(int, Fragment, String) line: 389    
MyPagerAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter).instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int) line: 99   
MyViewPager(ViewPager).addNewItem(int, int) line: 832   
MyViewPager(ViewPager).populate(int) line: 982  
MyViewPager(ViewPager).populate() line: 914 
MyViewPager(ViewPager).onMeasure(int, int) line: 1436   
MyViewPager(View).measure(int, int) line: 8171  
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 3132
... More calls <snipped>
```

In `BackStackRecord.doAppOp` it fails because the container ID (i.e. the ID of the `MyViewPager` is different from the `Fragment` ID. Here is the code for that method:

```
private void doAddOp(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag, int opcmd) {
    fragment.mFragmentManager = mManager;

    if (tag != null) {
        if (fragment.mTag != null && !tag.equals(fragment.mTag)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't change tag of fragment "
                    + fragment + ": was " + fragment.mTag
                    + " now " + tag);
        }
        fragment.mTag = tag;
    }

    if (containerViewId != 0) {
        if (fragment.mFragmentId != 0 && fragment.mFragmentId != containerViewId) {
            // IT FAILS HERE!
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't change container ID of fragment "
                    + fragment + ": was " + fragment.mFragmentId
                    + " now " + containerViewId);
        }
        fragment.mContainerId = fragment.mFragmentId = containerViewId;
    }

    Op op = new Op();
    op.cmd = opcmd;
    op.fragment = fragment;
    addOp(op);
}
```

I know that the container ID is the ID of the custom `ViewPager` because it is its ID that is passed through in the `instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)` call. In my case, the ID of the `MyViewPager` instance is 213129631**9** and the ID of the `Fragment` is 213129631**8**, hence it fails.

Where am I taking the wrong turn here? What am I misunderstanding in the whole `ViewPager`/`FragmentPagerAdapter`/`Fragment` concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
     switch (position) {
     case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES: // 0
        return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filtered_recipes_fragment);

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES: // 1
            return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.selected_recipes_fragment);

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST: // 2
            return mMyActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.shopping_list_fragment);

        default:
            return null;
}
```

you have to return a new instance of your `Fragment`s and not an existing one, which has already a parent and, hence, a container assinged. Remove the `Fragment`s you declared in your layout, and change your `getItem` like

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position) {
    case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES: // 0
        return new FilteredRecipesFragment();

    case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES: // 1
        return new SelectedRecipesFragment();

    case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST: // 2
        return new ShoppingListFragment()

    default:
        return null;
}
```

Comment: The reason I did this in the first place was that I need to maintain the state in each of the `Fragment`s. They all have some arrays containing data for `ListFragments` inside them which are updated from a database, so need the data to persist when I swipe or change tab. What is the best practice for this? `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`? If I move the `Fragment`s away from my main `layout.xml`, where should I put them? In their own XML file?

Comment: in your case `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter` shouldn't make much difference. `FragmentPagerAdapter` should keep the fragments in memory, so you don't have to worry about the data. Also if your data is on the DataBase and you are using a ContentProvider and a Loader, reloading is not a big deal. *If I move the Fragments away from my main layout.xml, where should I put them? In their own XML file?*  Neither. Just instantiate it a Runtime. The ViewPager takes care of handle the transaction for you

Comment: Yes, you are right, the data persists. I just got confused with the `new` meaning, well, creating a *new* `Fragment`. I didn't realize that it reuses the old `Fragment` in this case. Have I understood this correctly? That is, that the `Fragment`s are reused when doing it like this? This is a trade-off between memory usage and CPU, right?

Comment: yes the `Fragment`s are persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reason for the issue is when you're trying to add the same fragment twice. Illustrated below

```
public void populateFragments() {
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        //fragment is added for the first time
        addFragment(fragment);

        // fragment is added for the second time
        // This call will be responsible for the issue. The 
        addFragment(fragment);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = AppView.createFrameLayout(context);
        view.addView(frameLayout);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(frameLayout.getId(), fragment).commit();
    }
```